# Find specific row after the row in the time span

Tags: sql

I am struggling to find the first row with class='Physics' over student in the period of 3 hours beginning from the date of the first row's date by student.

I created rnum as row_number() Over(partition by student order by date)

The table I have:

```
| student | class      | date  | rnum |
| ------- | ---------- | ----- | ---- |
| 1       | Math       | 16:00 | 1    |
| 1       | Physics    | 16:30 | 2    |
| 1       | Biology    | 16:50 | 3    |
| 1       | Chemistry  | 19:00 | 4    |
| 1       | Math       | 20:00 | 5    |
| 1       | Physics    | 21:00 | 6    |
| 1       | Literature | 21:50 | 7    |
| 2       | Chemistry  | 9:00  | 1    |
| 2       | Math       | 10:00 | 2    |
| 2       | Math       | 12:00 | 3    |
| 2       | Geography  | 13:00 | 4    |
| 2       | Physics    | 17:00 | 5    |
| 3       | Math       | 13:00 | 1    |
| 3       | Math       | 14:40 | 2    |
| 3       | Physics    | 14:50 | 3    |
| 3       | Physics    | 14:55 | 4    |
| 3       | Literature | 17:00 | 5    |
```

And the expected result:

```
| student | class   | date  | rnum |
| ------- | ------- | ----- | ---- |
| 1       | Physics | 16:30 | 2    |
| 3       | Physics | 14:50 | 3    |
```

Comment: `16:00` is not a date, it looks like a time? Instead of row_number, look at *first_value*

Comment: @Stu I fixed it, but the meaning is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `timediff()` to check the time difference.

> ```
> create table classes (
> student int,
> class  char(10),
> t time,
> rnum int);
> insert into classes values
> (1,'Math','16:00',1   ),
> (1,'Physics ','16:30',2 ),
> (1,'Biology' ,'16:50',3 ),
> (1,'Chemistry' ,'19:00',4 ),
> (1,'Math' ,'20:00',5 ),
> (1,'Physics' ,'21:00',6 ),
> (1,'Literature' ,'21:50',7 ),
> (2,'Chemistry ','09:00',1 ),
> (2,'Math ','10:00',2 ),
> (2,'Math ','12:00',3 ),
> (2,'Geography' ,'13:00',4 ),
> (2,'Physics ','17:00',5 ),
> (3,'Math' ,'13:00',1 ),
> (3,'Math' ,'14:40',2 ),
> (3,'Physics ','14:50',3 ),
> (3,'Physics ','14:55',4 ),
> (3,'Literature ','17:00',5);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> with f as (
>   select 
>     student as stud,
>     min(t) as firstClass
>   from classes
>   group by student
>   ),
> s as (
>   select
>     student,
>     class, 
>     firstClass,
>     t date,
>     row_number() Over(partition by student order by t) ranking,
>     timediff(t,firstClass)
>   from classes c
>   join f
>   on c.student = f.stud
>   where class = 'Physics'
>   and timediff(t,firstClass) <= '03:00:00' 
>   )
> select *
> from s 
> where ranking = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> student | class   | firstClass | date     | ranking | timediff(t,firstClass)
> ------: | :------ | :--------- | :------- | ------: | :---------------------
>       1 | Physics | 16:00:00   | 16:30:00 |       1 | 00:30:00              
>       3 | Physics | 13:00:00   | 14:50:00 |       1 | 01:50:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f4a141317bae1d486f75a4ba38cc98f)*